# No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3 available for offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I did download gradle-3.3-all.zip from [here](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/), and extract that to `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.3\`

In Android Studio `File>Settings>Build, Execution,...>Build Tools>Gradle`
I changed setting to 'Use Local Gradle Distribution' and 'Gradle Home Path' changed to `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.3` and Offline Work in Global Gradle settings checked!

but this gradle error occur during build :

> Error:No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3
>   available for offline mode.

Also when I change the offline work to unchecked this error occur :

> Error:Could not GET
>   'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3/gradle-3.3.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required

Also this path `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/` 
does not contain gradle 3.3

what is my mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mixing gradle version and Android gradle plugin version.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0' // this is Android gradle plugin version
```

As of writing this, the [latest stable version](https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes.html) of gradle is `3.5`. The [latest stable version](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#revisions) of Android Gradle plugin is `2.3.2`.